# How to format split method to accept null values in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to parse a text file that contains instructions and operands. My goal is to store the instructions and operands in their respective arrays. I read in the line as one normally would using Scanner and hasNextLine(), store line in a string, use split method with whitespace delimiter, store data2[0] in one array and data2[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jeUr.png)] in another. However, there are instructions in the "language" we're using that do not have any operands like POP and RETN. Other instructions look like this: ADDD 1, LOCO 0, SUBD 5, etc. This is how the file is formatted:

[image]

My main issue is that whenever my program encounters lone instructions, it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which I understand why it does due to the delimiter I used. It would work fine until it reaches POP.

How can I change my code so that it accepts it and stores the instructions in their proper arrays while still using split(" ") and not changing the formatting of the input file?

```
 while((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        data2 = line2.split(" "); 
        opCode[i] = data2[0];
        operand[operand.length-(i+2)] = data2[1];}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to access `data2[1]` when it does not exist. Put an if condition before the last line where check if data2.length > 1

Comment: As I recall, some instructions have more than one operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the array length

```
data2 = line2.split(" "); 
opCode[i] = data2[0];
operand[operand.length-(i+2)] = data2.length == 2 ? data2[1] : null;
```

The last line assigns *null* for instructions without operands. Alternatively, you can use an empty string (`""`) as well.

Side note: I'm not sure why you are indexing `operand.length - (i + 2)` and not just `i`.

Comment: Hi. It seems like checking the length fixed it. Also, I didn't use `i` because we were instructed to store the items starting at the second to last index of the array, and saving the last index for something else. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the operands in the array, check the `len` if `if(len==2)` then only
add to the operands array.

```
  String[] opcode = new String[1];
  String[] operands = new String[1];
  int ilen = 0;
  int olen = 0;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                int len = line.split(" ").length;
                opcode[ilen] = line.split(" ")[0];
                opcode = Arrays.copyOf(opcode, opcode.length + 1);
                ilen++;

                if (len == 2) {
                    operands[olen] = line.split(" ")[1];
                }

                operands = Arrays.copyOf(operands, operands.length + 1);
                olen++;
            }
```

**NOTE**: If you try to print the arrays, consider their size`opcode.length-1` and `operands.length-1`.
Consider the below example for printing the array.(Using Java8)

```
String[] finalOperands = operands;
            IntStream.range(0, operands.length-1).forEach((idx) -> {
                System.out.println(finalOperands[idx]);
            });
```